# How the operator ^ is used in C++

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I understand in C , the operator ^is used for bit-wise EX-OR. In one of the C++ code I saw the following lines where this operator is used:

```
 using namespace System::Threading;
 public ref class Expert : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
    int i ;
        float a ;


public:
    int count;
    Thread^ th;

     }
```

What is the meaning of ^ here ?

Comment: That isn't C++, it's C++/CLI which is a Microsoft extension of C++.

Comment: It means that the code isn't C++, but a somewhat similar language from Microsoft.  (I forget the name of the language, but it has C++ in it.)

Comment: In C++ (as in C) it is the bitwise exclusive-or (XOR) operator. In the context of your question, it is something completely different and not C++.

Answer (score 5):

That is not C++, it's a variant of C++ named C++/CLI and is a Microsoft extension to make managed .NET applications in C++.

The `^` when used like that is do denote managed pointers, i.e. memory that can be garbage collected.

Comment: Just for clarification I am asking:  do I need to use free() , to release such a memory ?

Comment: @gpuguy No, it can only be allocated with `gcnew` and will be free'd automatically. It's like creating new objects in C#.

Answer (score 3):

That's a .net reference type, in [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI)! That is, Expert::th is a reference to an instance of `System.Threading.Thread` (or `null`). You can also tell it's C++/CLI by the fact it's inheriting from a .net class.

Answer (score 3):

That's not C++, that's C++/CLI. The `^` stands for "handle" and is like a managed pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You will also see the ^ ("hat") symbol in C++/CX, which is C++ with a set of extensions that helps support Windows 8 (WinRT) development.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CX)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinRT#C.2B.2B_.28WRL.2C_Component_Extensions.29